# LSTM layer (keras) is causing all layers after it to constantly predict the same thing no matter the input

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, lstm, ocr

I have a model for OCR, which after 2-3 epochs gives the same output. When I predicted the values and looked at the output for each layer I realized that all layers after the 1st layer in the LSTM block output the same values no matter the output. Here is the model (or the parts related to the problem):

```
Processing = layers.Reshape((12,9472))(encoder)

Processing = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(Processing)

lstm = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences = True))(Processing)
lstm = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences = True))(lstm)
lstm = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences = True))(lstm)

outputs = layers.Dense(358,activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))(lstm)
outputs = layers.Dense(358, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))(outputs)
outputs = layers.Dense(l, activation='softmax',name='output')(outputs)

output = CTCLayer()(labels,outputs)
```

Everything after (and including) the 1st LSTM layer outputs the same value (not including the CTC layer thing due to it being removed for predictions).

Before picking the model apart I thought it may have been a dying relu problem so I replaced all of the activation functions which where relu with the leaky relu. Is there something wrong with my implementation? or what may be causing everything after the LSTM layer to "die". How would I fix the underlying issue?

Another weird thing is that even after it outputs the same thing the loss values reduce for some time (so from 20.5 - 16.2), so its still learning. I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the learning rate as I experimented with extremely small values (1e-10, it just took a lot longer to get to the point where all the outputs become the same which from my observation is between 22 and 16, in terms of loss)

FYI: the CTCLayer is the one from the code example from the keras website

```
class CTCLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.loss_fn = keras.backend.ctc_batch_cost

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype="int64")
        input_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int64")
        label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int64")

        input_length = input_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")
        label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len, 1), dtype="int64")

        loss = self.loss_fn(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
        self.add_loss(loss)

        return y_pred
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what you mean by "Everything after (and including) the 1st LSTM layer outputs the same value"?

It's not technically possible for that to be true and for the loss to be changing. Knowing nothing else about your model, it looks like it's probably over-parameterized relative to your dataset and/or training resources.

The layers that sticks out most to me are

```
Processing = layers.Reshape((12,9472))(encoder)

Processing = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(Processing)
```

This first dense layer will have ~1.2M parameters. This then leads into your (bidirectional) LSTM layers which each will have much smaller parameter sizes of 200k or less.

What is probably happening is that CTC loss is guiding the network to getting marginally closer to correct answers but because CTC looks at probabilities rather than the categorical output, these changes aren't apparent. And the very large parameter space is causing this to go quite slowly.

If I'm right about the overparameterization, the following should help a lot:

- Cut the top dense layer.
- Consider reducing your input vector size (9.5k is pretty huge IMO).
- Either reduce the size of the last two dense layers. I'm assuming `l` is less than 358, in which case you are going from 64 -> 358 -> less, creating a bottleneck. There's unlikely to be a benefit from making those last dense layers larger than the previous layer.
- Or, cut one or both of the last two dense layers.

As long as your loss is improving, you're actually decent shape, you'll just have to design a network that make those improvements useful.

One last note: Are you using CNNs for part of your network? I'm guessing you're referring to [this demo](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/). I would rebuild that demo almost exactly to start, and then tweak the network from there. For OCR having a CNN to do the initial image processing is usually extremely helpful.

Comment: I can try to explain it to you, its as if all the weights of the 1st lstm are 0 (so the output is constant no matter what) making all the other layers useless (for more information I had a discussion on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393008/lstm-layer-keras-is-causing-all-layers-after-it-to-constantly-predicting-the-s)